# Creating a Task that is not All Day

Tags: google-tasks-api

When using the Tasks API to add a new task, the added task shows as "All Day" in the Google Calendar app.
I cannot figure out how to change this using the API.

I add a task using the Tasks API.  In Calendar, it shows as "All Day". Using the Calendar app, If I uncheck the All Day checkbox for the task and save it, there is nothing different in the JSON returned for the task by the API, but the All Day state is persistent in Calendar app.  I wonder how they do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible using Google Tasks API v1:
https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks#resource:-task

> The due date only records date information; the time portion of the
> timestamp is discarded when setting the due date. It isn't possible to
> read or write the time that a task is due via the API.